# Вопрос по RewriteRule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть у меня удаленные страницы, но поисковики их все равно регулярно ищут
поэтому сделал редирект вот таким образом

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /preview.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)type=zabor-iz-rabici
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://chelzabor.ru/zabor-iz-rabici/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /preview.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)type=zabor-iz-profnastila
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://chelzabor.ru/zabor-iz-profnastila/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /preview.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)type=reshetki
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://chelzabor.ru/reshetki/ [R=301,L]
```

Первый вопрос, как сократить код, чтобы не прописывать для всех страниц, может регулярка какая?

Второй вопрос, При редиректе цепляется query хвост, т.е. мне нужно чтобы переход был на

```
chelzabor.ru/reshetki/
```

а по факту

```
chelzabor.ru/reshetki/?type=reshetki
```

Как отсечь лишнее?

Comment: Убрать переменные из результата можно поставив знак вопроса в конец цели редиректа. Например `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://chelzabor.ru/reshetki/? [R=301,L]`

Comment: Спасибо! Второй вопрос решен :)